# Could you pls tell me, How to add facebook pages via API using PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have not yet found solution to add facebook pages dynamically. Could you pls tell me, How to add facebook pages via API using PHP SDK?

Comment: facebook pages?? can you explain more please.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you ***can't*** add/*create* Facebook pages through Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually some websites are providing options to create facebook pages/Tabs using facebook applications from their own websites... for example : http://www.splashtab.com/ , please check it.

Comment: @Kumaravel: NO NO NO! it's not creating "pages/tabs"...it's creating **TABS**! There's a big difference!